# AIML - answering based on previous topic

Tags: chatbot, aiml

I'm currently coding a chatbot with AIML and I have the following question :
Can I with tags define answers based on the first question asked by the user.
It would be something like this :

**User : What is StackOverflow ?**

**Chatbot : Stack Overflow is a question and answer website for professional and enthusiast programmers.**

**User : What's its link ?**

**Chatbot : [www.stackoverflow.com/](http://www.stackoverflow.com/)**

How can we define an hierarchy like this ?

I'm new to AIML, I've looked and I can't figure it out ! Please help me and thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You can either do this with <that> tags or for more flexibility, set a predicate and then check it to see what action to take.

```
<category>
    <pattern>WHAT IS STACKOVERFLOW</pattern>
    <template>
        <think><set name="website">StackOverflow</set></think>
        Stack Overflow is a question and answer website for professional and enthusiast programmers.
    </template>
</category>

<category>
    <pattern>WHAT IS GOOGLE</pattern>
    <template>
        <think><set name="website">Google</set></think>
        Google is a search engine.
    </template>
</category>

<category>
    <pattern>WHAT IS ITS LINK</pattern>
    <template>
        <condition name="website">
            <li value="StackOverflow">www.stackoverflow.com</li>
            <li value="Google">www.google.com</li>
            <li>The link to where?</li>
        </condition>
    </template>
</category>
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! It's exactly what I've wanted